# Session being lost between controllers Asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Ok I am using a session variable to store a case Id that is linked between tables. I am using .net 3.1 I just need this simple value passed between controllers It appears to only work within the current controller.

Say Relationship Controller is this.

```
public class RelationShipsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MISDBContext _context;

    public RelationShipsController(MISDBContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }
// GET: RelationShips/Edit/5
    public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int? id) {
        if (id == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }

        var relationShips = await _context.RelationShips.FindAsync(id);
        if (relationShips == null) {
            return NotFound();
        }
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("relationShipId", relationShips.Id.ToString());
        HttpContext.Session.SetString("CaseId", relationShips.MisObjectId.ToString());
        return View(relationShips);
    }
}
```

This is the second controller where i wish to read in the above session.

```
public class VesselsController : Controller
{
    private readonly MISDBContext _context;

    public VesselsController(MISDBContext context) {
        _context = context;
        GetCompanies();
    }
// POST: Vessels/Create
// To protect from overposting attacks, enable the specific properties you want to bind to, for 
// more details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=317598.
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name,CountryOfOrigon,CompanyId,IMONumber,Flag,Company,Country,CallSign,MMSI,VesselType,Active,isDeleted,isActive,CreatedDate,CreatedBy,MISObjectId,RelationShipId")] Vessels vessels)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid) {
            var realtionShipId = Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("relationShipId"), out int resultRelationshipId);

            Int32.TryParse(HttpContext.Session.GetString("CaseId"), out Int32 resultCaseId);
            vessels.isActive = true;
            vessels.isDeleted = false;
            vessels.CreatedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Intitals");
            vessels.LastModfiedDate = DateTime.Now;                
            vessels.CreatedDate = DateTime.Now;
            vessels.LastModfiedBy = HttpContext.Session.GetString("Intitals");                
            vessels.MISObjectId = resultCaseId;
            vessels.RelationShipId = resultRelationshipId;
            _context.Add(vessels);
            await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Relationships", new { Id = vessels.MISObjectId });

        }
        GetCompanies();
        return View(vessels);
    }
}
```

Its this resultCaseId I have lost the variable and yes I have  setup the configure middle ware.

```
 app.UseSession();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you as the user have [provided consent](https://andrewlock.net/session-state-gdpr-and-non-essential-cookies/). Or mark the session cookie as "essential" like this:

```
services.AddSession(opts => 
{
    opts.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // make the session cookie Essential
});
```

You can read more about GDPR changes in asp.net core [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/gdpr?view=aspnetcore-2.2).

Comment: Yes sorry i should have explaiend that